# Maven POM equivalent for-DargLine="-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR"

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm migrating to java11 and I'm running this commmand

```
mvn clean install -DargLine="-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR"
```

it works fine, but is there a POM equivalent to pass that argLine so I just can use mvn clean install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the property inside the POM

```
<properties>
  <argLine>java.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR</argLine>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added "-D" To the previous answer from J Fabian Meier for my project since I was using maven-surefire-plugin version 2.22.2 on a child of a parent pom.xml. The child ran all the tests but it seemed the pom.xml parent didn't propagate the argline property to the children. It also gave an error when running argline without the added '-D' on the maven-surefire plugin configuration. Now it looks like this and the tests run and the argline propagates to the tests so  the parse error I was getting before are fixed.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                    <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                </includes>
                <argLine>-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```